# How to add caret below current slick element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, slick.js

We are using the [Slick Carousel](https://github.com/kenwheeler/slick) and need to add a caret below the current active item. In order to that we have the following below.

We have tried to use the :after element but that does not work. How would we be able to add the caret below the currently selected item outside of the blue border?

The problem we found is the the .slick-current has overflow: hidden, which is conflicting with the :after element. However, the overflow: hidden is needed for the carousel to work properly.

CSS breakdown:

1. blue border represent the outside container where we want the caret to reside
2. red marks the current active slide

```js
$(function() {
  $('.carousel').slick({
    arrows: true,
    focusOnSelect: true,
    infinite: false,
    centerMode: true,
    variableWidth: true
  });
});
```

```css
.carousel {
  color: black;
  display: block;
}
.flex {
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

.carousel > .item {
  background: black;
  color: white;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.slick-list {
 width: auto;
 margin: 0 auto;
 height: auto;
}

.slick-slide {
  padding: 10px;
}

.slick-current {
  color: red;
}

.slick-current:after {
  content: '';
  border-top: 10px solid blue;
  border-right: 10px solid transparent;
  border-left: 10px solid transparent;
  bottom: 100%;
  display: block;
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
}
```

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.8.1/slick-theme.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.8.1/slick.min.css">
<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.8.1/slick.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
<div class="flex">
      <div class="carousel">
        <div class="item">
           tab name - tab 1
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          tab name - tab 2
        </div>
        <div class="item">
           tab name - tab 3
        </div>
        <div class="item">
           tab name - tab 4
        </div>
        <div class="item">
           tab name - tab 5
        </div>
        <div class="item">
           tab name - tab 6
        </div>
      </div>

</div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Goal:

1. Get the caret to show up underneath the active item but also outside of the blue border

Current problem:
[image: current problem before]

Desired output
[image: desired output after]

current problem
[image: current under 3rd]

desired output
[image: desired output under 3rd]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. Maybe a mockup of the expected output would be a starting point. See the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: @GerardoBLANCO screenshots have been added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use the `position:absolute` for the caret and position:relative to the `.slick-current` class...

...use `bottom:10px` and `transform` to center the caret icon...

...now the problem is `overflow:hidden` in the `.slick-slider .slick-list` class which prevent the visibility of the arrow icon outside of the blue border...

...so to fix that set `overflow:visible` to `.slick-slider .slick-list` and wrap your `flex` div into another div `.overflow` having `overflow:hidden` and `padding-bottom:15px` for visibility of caret

***Stack Snippet***

```js
$(function() {
  $('.carousel').slick({
    arrows: true,
    focusOnSelect: true,
    infinite: false,
    centerMode: true,
    variableWidth: true
  });
});
```

```css
.carousel {
  color: black;
  display: block;
}

.flex {
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

.carousel>.item {
  background: black;
  color: white;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.slick-slider .slick-list {
  width: auto;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: auto;
  overflow: visible;
}

.slick-slide {
  padding: 10px;
}

.slick-current {
  color: red;
  position: relative;
}

.slick-current:after {
  content: '';
  border-top: 10px solid blue;
  border-right: 10px solid transparent;
  border-left: 10px solid transparent;
  bottom: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -10px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}

.overflow {
  overflow: hidden;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
}

/*Remove blue glow on focus*/
add .item {
    -moz-appearance: none;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
}

.item:focus {
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    box-shadow: none !important;
    outline: none !important;
}
```

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.8.1/slick-theme.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.8.1/slick.min.css">
<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.8.1/slick.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="overflow">
        <div class="flex">
          <div class="carousel">
            <div class="item">
              tab name - tab 1
            </div>
            <div class="item">
              tab name - tab 2
            </div>
            <div class="item">
              tab name - tab 3
            </div>
            <div class="item">
              tab name - tab 4
            </div>
            <div class="item">
              tab name - tab 5
            </div>
            <div class="item">
              tab name - tab 6
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: in this scenario this appears to work. after further testing I have found another issue for which i will see if i can ask another questions.

Comment: @drupi17 what is the problem?

Comment: @GerardoBLANCO when there is an element below the carousel that has a color, the caret ends up above the image. Let me see if i can get a good picture.

Comment: @drupi17 maybe make a new question and post the link here so we can go and help you

Comment: @GerardoBLANCO okay, let me first confirm if they still want this new requirement so i don't use up your time.

Comment: @GerardoBLANCO looks like the requirement is not needed, what has been provided will work.

Comment: @drupi17 well until the next time. Code On!